# Unscrambling words in a sentence using Natural Language Generation

Tags: algorithm, parsing, nlp, artificial-intelligence, fsm

I have a sentence in English. Now I want to jumble the words up and input that set of words into a program which should unscramble the words according to normal rules of English grammar to output the original sentence. I can vaguely assume it would require Natural Language Generation algorithms.

For eg:

Sentence: Mary has gone for a walk with her dog.
Set of words:   {has, for, a, with, her, dog, Mary, gone, walk}

The output should be the same sentence.

I can assume only the set of words will never be enough to generate the original sentence. But what more information must be included to revive the original sentence?
Please guide me as to where I should be starting with.

Comment: Sounds vaguely like your professor would like you to discover link grammar, but I'm nominating to close as too broad. In any event, you need a lot more lexical information to get anywhere (part of speech, valency [i.e. transitivity] of the verb, contextual disambiguation) as well as some sort of grammatical framework.

Comment: Is it like creating a set of sentences, given a set of "words"?

Comment: I would be interested in creating a single sentence.

Answer (score 4):

[Language models](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_model) are things that can take in a text or sentence (any sequence of words) and assign it a probability based on how well the model "recognizes" that text.

To solve your problem, you could take a language model and use it to compute the probability of each possible permutation you can make of the input words. The most probable sentence accord to the model is probably the most coherent one.

For a situation like yours, trying a n-gram model (for n > 2.. I think 2 or 3 should do the trick) or a Hidden Markov model leveraging part of speech tags should do the trick.

Comment: Parsing each combination can help you focus on candidates that form a sentence and choose among them.

Comment: Actually, I want the input to be a set of words, without the sequence that is followed in language. Thanks for the idea regarding the n-gram model. But could you help me with how could I generate any of those sequences that can be accepted by the language model, from just a jumbled set of words?

Comment: You generate every possible permutation of words in your input and see which one gets the highest probability according to your language model. For example if the input received is {A, B, C}, you try "A B C", "A C B", "B A C", "B C A", "C A B", "C B A".. whichever one gets the highest probability according to your model is the one that is most likely to be a real sentence.

Comment: That seems a great idea adi92. May be we could use some method to generate the permutations following some general rules of English Grammar, which should eventually reduce the number of possible permutations thus increasing its efficiency?

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to solve your problem without additional information. Take this example:

```
{"happy", "you" "are"}
```

Can **you** reconstruct the sentence? Is it "You are happy" or is it "Are you happy"? Note that the words are the same but the meaning changes radically. No matter how good algorithm you write it will not be able to reconstruct the sentence if you can not.

Comment: Or equivalently "Her dog has gone for a walk with Mary", as well as the question forms of the candidate sentences.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter but would speculate that the downvote is for not actually attempting to solve the OP's problem. I would rather flag as "Not an answer" (but have not done that either, as I consider this informative and relevant nevertheless).

Comment: Yeah I was aware that without additional information it would be impossible. But could you enlighten on what exact additional information is necessary? I mean parts of speech information or subject-object information or what?

Comment: @user3742268 I am not sure that even that will be enough. Probably you will need data which words are negated, what is the sentence - a question a statement or exclamation. Also you will need to know which is the object and which is the subject. Think of another example: `{"I", "working", "paid", "being", "am", "without"}` This could be `"I am working without being paid"` or `"I am being paid without working"` Makes huge difference right?

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev though u r points are correct i think u misunderstood the question. He just wants the set words to be rearranged into valid english sentence doesnt matter what it means

Comment: `The output should be the same sentence.` this does not sound like what you claim

Comment: Ivaylo Strandjev, Vikram Bhat: I was thinking of getting back the original sentence itself. Actually I wanted to proceed by creating a valid english sentence and then add more information to the set of words to get the original sentence itself. In any case thanks for your suggestions both.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do following thing to get started :-

> 1. Maintain a dictionary of english words classified as nouns,adjectives,verbs,etc.
> 2. Build grammer rules for english language which you can get from any english tutorial.
> 3. try to rearrange the words to match the grammer rules.

**Note:-** English is very ambiguous language so you might end with something else.

eg.

> grammer rule : article noun verb
>
> input words : dog , barks , the
>
> dictionary lookup : dog => noun , barks => verb , the => article
>
> rearrange the words according to the rule.
>
> There can be mutliple rule and word can also be of multiple type so
>   try all possibilities.

Comment: Thanks Vikram, this was what I was wondering. I was planning to use the dictionary with the word type stored for each word and wanted to generate something like a finite state machine to generate the correct sentence if possible. But could you help me with where to start with?

Comment: @user372268 i think first u need to gather words and their type from internet resources. The may build a hashmap using the words which map it to the type. Then learn some typical english grammer rules for online tutorials or from teacher.

Comment: @user3742268 You might wanna build a parser using bison c++ to check if sentence is valid using grammer rules but then you might need to try all permutations of words but instead try the set of tokens directly with each grammer using backtracking approach.

Comment: Alright, I will try to proceed that way. Thanks a lot.