# Creating Rules for Word Permutations Based on a word's POS Tag

Tags: csv, python-3.x, nlp, permutation, nltk

I have another question and since this community has been so great helping me along I thought I would give it another shot.

Right now I have Python 3 code that imports a CSV file where the first column is full of words in the following format:

```
The
Words
Look
Like
This
In
A
Column
```

Once this CSV file is uploaded and read by Python, the words are tagged using an NLTK POS Tagger.  From there, permutations are made from all of the words and then the results are exported to a new CSV file.
Right now, my full code goes like this

```
Import CSV
with open(r'C:\Users\jkk\Desktop\python.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    J = []
    for row in reader:
      J.extend(row)
import nltk
D = nltk.pos_tag(J)
C = list(itertools.permutations(D, 3))
with open('test.csv', 'w') as a_file:
    for result in C:
    result = ' '.join(result)
    a_file.write(result + '\n')
```

**My question is, how does one make rules for the word permutations based on the word tag?**  More specifically, the reason I am tagging words is because I don't want nonsense permutations (i.e. The This In / A This In / etc).  Once the words are tagged with their respective part of speech, how do I code rules based on their tag (for example): Never have two "DT" labeled words follow each other (i.e. "The" and "A").  Or always have a NN tagged word be followed by a VBG tagged word (i.e. "Looks" always comes after "Words")?  And then finally, once those rules are implemented, get rid of the tags so that just the original words remain? I realize this is a general question but any guidance would be very much appreciated on how to approach this question as I am still very new and learning every step of the way!  Any resources, code, or even advice would help!  Thank you again for taking the time to read this long post!

Comment: how does your whole csv file look like? why do you need a csv file when you only have one column?

Comment: Have a look at this discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24229863/unscrambling-words-in-a-sentence-using-natural-language-generation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set of rules that define legal strings in a language is called a grammar (or formal grammar). There are many formalisms which allow you to express these rules. One that is reasonnably simple to experiment with is a context free grammar ([CFG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_free_grammar)). NLTK comes with tools to generate strings from these. Here is the [NLTK book's chapter on syntax](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch08.html). They go into much more depth.

The following code is for python 3 with NLTK 3.0a4. The API changed between NLTK 2 and 3, so it will not run on the older version.

```
from nltk import ContextFreeGrammar
from nltk.parse.generate import generate
from ntlk.util import trigrams

# build a simple grammar
cfg = """
S -> NP VP
VP -> VBZ NP
NP -> DT | NN | DT NN | DT JJ NN | JJ NN
"""

# you get these from your csv
words = "this is a simple sentence".split()
tagged = set(pos_tag(words))
# Add the words to the grammar
for word, tag in tagged:
    cfg += "{tag} -> '{word}'\n".format(word=word, tag=tag)
grammar = parse_cfg(cfg)

valid_trigrams = set()

language = generate(grammar)
for valid_sentence in language:
    valid_trigrams.update(list(trigrams(valid_sentence)))

print(valid_trigrams)
# {('simple', 'sentence', 'is'), ('this', 'is', 'this'), ('a', 'sentence', 'is'), ('sentence', 'is', 'a'), ('a', 'is', 'a'), ('this', 'is', 'simple'), ('sentence', 'is', 'this'), ('this', 'is', 'sentence'), ('is', 'a', 'sentence'), ('is', 'a', 'simple'), ('a', 'simple', 'sentence'), ('a', 'is', 'this'), ('this', 'simple', 'sentence'), ('this', 'is', 'a'), ('is', 'simple', 'sentence'), ('a', 'is', 'simple'), ('this', 'sentence', 'is'), ('is', 'this', 'sentence'), ('sentence', 'is', 'sentence'), ('sentence', 'is', 'simple'), ('is', 'this', 'simple'), ('a', 'is', 'sentence')}
```

There is a limitation to this approach though, since a context free grammar cannot cover all of English. There is no known way of validating syntax for English anyways though, so you can only have an approximate solution.

Another thing you should be aware of is that the POS tagger assumes that the order of words is relevant. Roughly, it gives each word a set of possible tags, then refines it based on the preceding and or following words, so if you're CSV contains sentences, then you are ok, otherwise, you might want to specify the unigram pos tagger `nltk.tag.UnigramTagger`, but regardless, you will only get the most common tag. This will be an issue for words like "run" which can be a verb or a noun ("a morning run" vs "I run").